# Is there a way to calculate an equation with n raised to the power of x?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I'm trying to solve x in the following equation using python;

```
 20 = 3^x - x - 4
```

I've tried with sympy solve() but rather than outputting the result of solving x, it outputs another equation.

Current code:

```
x = Symbol('x', integer = True)
eqn = Eq(3**x - x - 4, 20)
r = solve(eqn)
```

Expected output:

```
r = −24, 3
```

Actual output:

```
[-24 - LambertW(-log(3)/282429536481)/log(3), -24 - LambertW(-log(3)/282429536481, -1)/log(3)]
```

Comment: The answer you get is correct. It is not in the pretty form. I assume that is because sympy is using general methods to solve it, and in general there will be no pretty integer answers. If you pose this as a number theory question, requiring integer solutions then I assume that the problem gets immensly harder

Comment: You can use these generic solutions. Compute the values as floats and conjecture that they are ints, then confirm by substitution

Comment: This may be a bug. 3 is a real and valid solution however Sympy is correct with the answer for when x=-24. 3^-24 is close to 0 so a lot of calculators will set it to - which leads to a floating-point error with the actual answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sympy is giving the correct answer here, the answers only happen to be very close to -24 and 3. For example, Wolfram Alpha says the answers are -23.99999999999645929383851407736751424572557264463826050688997713695590353717193719618212151198215945 and 3, see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+3%5Ex+-+x+-+4+%3D+20. And indeed, sympy agrees:

```
>>> sympy.N(r[0], 100)
-23.99999999999645929383851407736751424572557264463826050688997713695590353717193719618212151198215945
>>> sympy.N(r[1], 100)
3.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```